# State inside an Akka actor with Okku Clojure library

Tags: clojure, akka

I'm trying to use Akka in a Clojure application using the Okku library. I'm very new to Akka. I'm stuck on how I can create a state variable in an actor that gets initialized for each instantiation of the actor.

I'm using a setup very similar to the Pi example in the Okku project. I have a master coordinator actor that spawns some number of worker actors to perform some work. The master reads an Avro file and dispatches a message containing what was read from each Avro record to the workers.

The problem I'm stuck on right now is how to create an object in each of the worker actors when they are instantiated that they can reuse for each message. I'm working with UIMA here and creating a new jCAS object is an expensive operation (it really throws the garbage collector into a tizzy if you create too many of them), so I want to create a jCAS object with the working is instantiated and reuse that object each time the worker receives a message.

Here is my first attempt that clearly doesn't work correctly (it's creating a single jCas object that is shared by all the workers.

```
(defn worker
 "Individual worker actor to process a single file."
 [countfn]
 (let [jcas (atom nil)]
   (okku/actor
     (preStart [] (reset! jcas (JCasFactory/createJCas)))
     (onReceive [{t :type doc :document}]
              (okku/dispatch-on t
                   :processdoc (do (uima/deserialize-xmi-jcas @jcas doc)
                                   (! (m-result (countfn @jcas)))))))))
```

Is it possible to give each worker instance its own `jcas` object using Okku or do I need to use `gen-class` somehow to make a subclass of `UntypedActor`?